# CSS drop down div gets disabled on fixing nav position

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS.
I am developing a horizontal scrolling website, so I need the nav bar on the top always.

Made a nav bar using HTML/CSS, but when I try to mark the position of  as fixed, the drop down div gets disabled.

```
nav {
  [...]
  position: 'fixed'; //writing this causes drop-down div to get disabled
}
```

Nav bar code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FA6WG/

I've commented the problematic line in CSS inside nav{}.

Comment: can I know why it has been marked down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the usage of `overflow: hidden` in `nav`

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FA6WG/2/)

Why are you using `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. It solved my problem. I was using overflow : hidden because I wanted to hide the menu when user is not hovering over it.